# Search Unix file name by positions of the characters in file name

Tags: files, filenames, search

I have 2 files.

1. File 1 = ABC2019120601C
2. File 2 = ABC2019120611C

If I type ls -l ABC*C it will output all 2 files. Is there a way to find files by exact position of the character?

For example

- 1st position = A
- 2nd position = B
- 3rd position = C
- and 14th position = C

Then it will output only the file ABC2019120601C
Please help if this is possible

Comment: Your criteria would match both files.  Please elaborate.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `?` to match any single character (as opposed to `*` which matches zero or more characters). So for example

```
ls -ld ABC??????????C
```

Note however that *both* of your example filenames match your criteria (they differ only in the 12th character).

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`, you can do:

```
set -o extendedglob # best in ~/.zshrc
ls -ld ABC?(#c10)C*
```

Where `(#cx,y)` is like regexp `{x,y}` to specify an interval of repetitions of the previous atom (here `?` that matches any single character).

The equivalent in ksh93 would be:

```
ls -ld ABC{10}(?)C*
```

`bash`/`sh` have no equivalent, but assuming `$IFS` doesn't contain `?` characters, you should be able to do it like:

```
repeat() {
  awk -- '
    BEGIN {
      for (i = 0; i < ARGV[1]; i++) printf "%s", ARGV[2]
      if (ARGV[1]) printf "\n"
    }' "$@"
}

ls -ld ABC$(repeat 10 '?')C
```

To search by position, with ksh93, you could use its look-ahead operators:

```
ls -ld ~(P:(?=.{0}(A))(?=.{1}(B))(?=.{2}(C))(?=.{13}(C))*
```

Where the offsets are: 0, 1, 2, 13

- `~(P:...)`: ksh93 globs can use a variety of different syntaxes. Here using perl-like regexps.
- `(?=...)` is positive look-ahead assertion like in perl, that matches on the spot with 0 width if what's inside matches.
- `.{13}(C)`: matches C followed by 13 characters. As all the `(?=...)` match with zero width, they end up all matching at the beginning of the subject). We're using `.{13}(C)` instead of `.{13}C` to work around a bug in ksh93.

With `zsh`, you could do the same by doing the PCRE match in a glob qualifier:

```
set -o rematchpcre
ls -ld *(e['[[ $REPLY =~ "^(?=.{0}A)(?=.{1}B)(?=.{2}C)(?=.{13}C)" ]]'])
```

Or do

```
ls -ld *(e['[[ $REPLY[1,3]$REPLY[14] = ABCC ]]'])
```

Or use a helper function like:

```
offsets() {
  local c o
  for o c {
    [[ $REPLY[o] = $c ]] || return
  }
}
ls -ld *(e['offsets 1 A 2 B 3 C 14 C'])
```